# PyDotNet call generic method from Python

Tags: c#, python, generics

I'm using PyDotnet to expose a .NET library in Python. I've hit a snag where I need to call a generic method, but can't figure out the syntax or if it's simply not supported.

e.g.
`public T DoSomething<T>(T MyData) { ... }`

How would I call this from Python?

**Update:**

That is the correct syntax, thank you. However, in my case I get an exception trying to call the method with the type. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using that syntax but I'm still getting an exception.

The .NET method declaration looks like:

```
public T SpliceSeries<T>(
            T lowPriorityTimeSeries, 
            T highPriorityTimeSeries)
        where T : UserScripting.TimeSeries
```

In python I'm calling it as follows:

```
myInstance.SpliceSeries[DerivedTimeSeriesType](myarg1, myarg2)
NB where myarg1 & 2 are of type DerivedTimeSeriesType, which is .NET class derived from UserScripting.TimeSeries.
```

The exception is:

> Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception. at InteropPython.throw_invalid_cast(basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator > ) at InteropPython.DynamicCallableInstance.Invoke(DynamicCallableInstance , object , tuple args)

Is there anything I can do to debug this under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think generics are supported through [] syntax,
DoSomething[T]

Comment: Yes, that's the syntax, but in my case I'm getting an exception.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?